# Sci-fi book with 3 races of humans?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book where there are 3 versions of the human race. The simulated humans, robotic humans, and organic humans.

Either the robotic or simulated humans finds out about a disaster, I think a supernova, that wipes out the organic humans.

I don't remember what happens next, but I think the robotic humans go all around the galaxy and start trying to trail a alien species through several dimensions.

Anybody know the name of this book?

Comment: [Feersum Enjinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feersum_Endjinn) shares a lot of these concepts.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE! You might want to bring your question to a more readable state by using semicolons, paragraphs and bullets. Also, any other details, including year of publication or language, would be of great help.

Comment: Could you contact the person who told you about it and ask them?

Answer (score 11):

This is Greg Egan's *Diaspora*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(novel)):

> By 2975 CE (Universal Time), the year in which the novel begins, humanity has "speciated" into three distinct groupings:
>
> fleshers, biological societies consisting of statics, the original, naturally-evolving race of Homo sapiens...
>
> gleisner robots, individual software-based intelligences housed inside artificial anthropoid, or flesher-shaped, physical bodies ...
>
> the citizens, intelligence as disembodied computer software running entirely within simulated reality-based communities known as polises.